# Firebase sms auto fill not working after app published to play store

Tags: flutter, firebase

looking for some help with the auto-fill OTP function for my app while using Firebase authentication service. Auto fill functionality works fine in test app as sms has the hash code. But when I publish the app on Google Playstore, the hash code in the OTP authentication sms is replaced by the app name, and hence the sms auto fill stops working as it requires the hash code.  Will be great if someone has come across this problem and can help with some solution or workaround.

What's is the workaround to this

Comment: check you sha2 at your final app, because when you compile it sometimes the SHA become difference

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and mine was due to the app name too long to contain the hash-code. Below are few work around:

You need to make sure the message you receive contains the hash of your app. Below is the right format :
123456 is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.
xyz_hascode_123

If your SMS does not contain the hashCode at the end, you might have to shorten your app name to less than 16 characters.

If your app is already published on Google Play, the name in the SMS will be the same as the one in the GooglePlayStore.

If you changed the name to 15 characters and the error still persists, you might have to wait for at least 24hours for the change to reflect on Firebase.

If after all the above it's still not resolved, please check if your receiver is well configured in the code.

Check out the new GooglePlay policy on app names: [Common app names violations](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9898842?hl=en#zippy=%2Cexamples-of-common-violations)